# Python- search for two lists of keywords

Tags: python, string, list, keyword, fuzzywuzzy

how can I apply fuzzy-wuzzy search on two lists which can give me below output. The two lists are as following:

```
list_of_keys=['azure', 'job', 'matlab', 'javascript', 'http', 'android', 'amazon', 'apache spark'] 


result=['apache http server', 'angularjs', 'azure bot service', 'amazon s3', 'android sdk', 'android studio', 'amazon cloudfront']
```

**Required Output:**

1-Word from Resume: apache spark, Word from JSON data: apache http server

2-Word from Resume: amazon, Word from JSON data: amazon s3, amazon cloudfront

3-Word from Resume: http, Word from JSON data: apache http server

I am looking for a fuzzywuzzy search approach.
I want is if there is any match in two lists e.g if 'apache spark' gets matched with result list 'apache http server' then it should print as an output: Word from Resume: apache spark, Word from JSON data: apache http server. Similarly, if amazon is matched then it should print as an output: Word from Resume: amazon, Word from JSON data: amazon s3, amazon cloudfront and also display the score/value. I have been searching on the internet but couldn't find any. Your help in this regard will be appreciated.

**I used this approach which is a simple one:**

```
for item in list_of_keys: 
    for item1 in result: 
        if item in item1: 
            print("Word from Resume: ", item, ", Word from JSON data: ", item1)
print ("****************\n")
```

**2nd approach I used but it is not searching anything from 2nd list:**

Below code is for FuzzyWuzzy Search which doesnot work properly

```
def match_term(term, list_of_keys, min_score=0):
    # -1 score in case I don't get any matches
    max_score = -1
    
    # return empty for no match 
    max_name = ''
    
    # iterate over all names in the other
    for term2 in list_of_keys:
        # find the fuzzy match score
        score = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(term, term2)
    
        # checking if I am above my threshold and have a better score
        if (score > min_score) & (score > max_score):
            max_name = term2
            max_score = score
    return (max_name, max_score)


# list for dicts for easy dataframe creation
dict_list = []

#iterating over the sales file
for name in list_of_keys:
    #use the defined function above to find the best match, also set the threshold to a chosen #
    match = match_term(name, result, 94)
    
    #new dict for storing data
    dict_ = {}
    dict_.update({'Resume': name})
    dict_.update({'JSON Data': match[0]})
    dict_.update({'score': match[1]})
    
    dict_list.append(dict_)
print(dict_list)
```

Comment: I have edited my post with my code.

Comment: please edit your question and fix the grammatical errors, to make you question more understandable

Comment: @Yousaf--fuzzywuzzy doesn't find matches since your min score of 94 is too high i.e. `match = match_term(name, result, 94)`.  Use a smaller value.  You can use 0 to get an idea of the type of matches it finds.

Comment: @DarrylG Thank you for your suggestion, It's working fine when I set the threshold to 60. Much appreciated.